# MySQL distinct results on duplicate multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, logic

I have table:

```
env | app | prop_file | prop | value
qa1   e     a           a      testa
qa1   g     b           a      testa
qa1   s     c           a      testb
qa2   s     a           b      testc
qa2   s     d           b      testc
qa3   a     a           b      testc
qa4   z     g           c      testb
qa4   x     a           c      testb
```

I need the following result:

```
env | prop_file | prop | value
qa1   a           a      testa
qa1   c           a      testb
```

I'll try to summarize, I need only results where the "value" of a given "prop" do not match within a specific "env".  If the "prop_file" or other colums don't match, then it doesn't matter.  Also in the results I need the prop files for the columns that don't match.  In reality I could also live with the following results:

```
env | prop_file | prop | value
qa1   a           a      testa
qa1   b           a      testa
qa1   c           a      testb
```

I have tried a bunch of joins and groups and counts but can't seem to nail down the exect syntax!  Is driving me nuts.  If needed I can provide more examples in my source table.

Comment: Translate this: `I need only results where the "value" of a given "prop" do not match within a specific "env"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gets the list of env/prop where you have a problem:

```
select env, prop
from t
group by env, prop
having count(distinct value) > 1;
```

This joins back to the original table to get the records with the problem:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select env, prop
      from t
      group by env, prop
      having count(distinct value) > 1
     ) tep
     on t.env = tep.env and t.prop = tep.prop;
```

Comment: This was perfect after I cleaned up some hidden characters in my table like carage returns.